# Calculation is wrong, + instead of - is used

Tags: c, math

I want to program a little calculator for training reasons.
Why is it calculating 10-6 = 16 instead of 10-6 = 4?

I got the error:

```
Assertion Failed!
Expression: calc("10-6") == 4 && "could not do substraction"
```

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>

double calc(char * input);
double extract_first_integer(char * input);
double extract_last_integer(char * input);
char extract_operand(char * input);

int main()
{
   assert(calc("10-6") == 4 && "could not do substraction");

   return 0;
}

double calc(char * input){
   double num1 = extract_first_integer(input);
   double num2 = extract_last_integer(input);
   char operand = extract_operand(input);
   printf("operand is %c\n", operand);
   switch (operand)
   {
   case '-':
      printf("num1 - num2: %f\n", num1-num2);  // output: 16 instead of 4
      return num1 - num2;
      break;
   }
}

double extract_first_integer(char * input){
   char *str = input, *p = str;
   double val;
   while (*p) { // While there are more characters to process...
      if ( isdigit(*p) || ( (*p=='-'||*p=='+') && isdigit(*(p+1)) )) {
         // Found a number
         val = strtol(p, &p, 10); // Read number
         return val;
      } else {
         // Otherwise, move on to the next character.
         p++;
      }
   }
}

double extract_last_integer(char * input){
   char *str = input, *p = str;
   double val;
   while (*p) { // While there are more characters to process...
      if ( isdigit(*p) || ( (*p=='-'||*p=='+') && isdigit(*(p+1)) )) {
         // Found a number
         val = strtol(p, &p, 10); // Read number
      } else {
         // Otherwise, move on to the next character.
         p++;
      }
   }
   return val;
}

char extract_operand(char * input){
   if (strstr(input, "-")) return '-';
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `extract_last_integer()` you have

```
while (*p) { // While there are more characters to process...
  if ( isdigit(*p) || ( (*p=='-'||*p=='+') && isdigit(*(p+1)) )) {
     // Found a number
     val = strtol(p, &p, 10); // Read number
  } else {
     // Otherwise, move on to the next character.
     p++;
  }
}
```

which increases `p` until it meets the first digit or `-`/`+` followed by a digit. So it'll match **the first `10` number**. However note that you're **not breaking the loop** like the early `return val;` in `extract_first_integer()`. As you continue matching the next digit the `-6` in `"10-6"` will be matched. And `10 - (-6)` is clearly 16

You're also likely having undefined behavior by

- passing the same pointer to `strtol`. The variable `str` is unused and should be passed in the `str_end` parameter instead
- passing a `const char*` (`"10-6"`) to a function expecting `char*`

The performance of the 3 `extract...` functions is also not good, since they all need to iterate from the start of the input string. To fix this you should return the position of the current digit and start the next function from that position. This way you can use the same function to parse integers instead of writing two

Besides, you have the names inverted. The two integers are called [*operands*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand) and the thing that connects 2 operands is called an [*operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)), not operand. And why returning `double` when you only read integers?

So after fixing those points we'll have

```
int extract_operand(char * input, size_t *lastChar);
char extract_operator(char * input, size_t *lastChar);

size_t lastPos;
int num1 = extract_operand(input, &lastPos);
char operand = extract_operator(input + lastPos, &lastPos);
int num2  = extract_operand(input + lastPos, &lastPos);
```

But this will only work for simple cases with a [binary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation) and 2 operands like this. For more complex situations you'll need a [tokenizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) to split the input stream to a list of tokens

Comment: It increases until it finds the first digit? I would say otherwise... and also it starts again from the beginning since the endptr of the strtol in extract_frist_integer is not used.

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon yes I was too sleepy and didn't read it carefully. I've fixed the answer